# Which metadata field do I use for the photographer in Aperture?

Tags: metadata, apple-aperture

I have a fair few photos in my Aperture library that have been taken by other photographers. I'd like to mark them with the photographer's name in a way that allows me to search easily, but I can't see a field for this in either the metadata inspector or the search dialogue. Which field do I use to accomplish this?

I'm using Aperture 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right field is IPTC / Contact / Creator.

You can freely choose which fields are displayed in the metadata inspector. So if you can't find the field "Creator" in the default set of fields that you are using, choose another set or choose "Edit..." and add the Creator field (under IPTC / Contact).

In the search tool, click "Add Rule", "IPTC", and select "Creator".